# Red5 viewing live broadcast, connection not found

Tags: java, red5, red5-recorder

Okay so I might be asking a silly question. I have setup Red5 on Windows and I am able to stream to /live/mystream using OBS. I am then able to view the live stream using the Red5 publisher page. However it I try to open this in VLC or any other media player that supports RTMP it is unable to connect and on the server I get connection not found. Thus I am assuming the url is rtmp://myip/live/mystream. Could someone give some assistance?

Thanks
P

Answer (score 0):

Port 1935 is the default port to access the red5 rtmp stream. So please check if port 1935 is open in your firewall and/or modem. You can test the port by using:

telnet myip 1935

If you get a blank screen the port is accessible. Otherwise, you get a connection failed message or something similar.